# Linux: Local storage largely consumed by excessive cache from pip

Tags: python, linux, pip

**Problem**

I've been experiencing a memory-related issue recently where a python script attempts to execute but receives the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last) :
    File "FiveMinutes.py", line 56, in <module>
        main()
    File "FiveMinutes.py", line 41, in main
        f.write('hello')
OSError: [Errno 28] No Space left on device
```

This however was just a flag to me that the disk space has reached it's maximum. So I checked this using `df`, like so:

```
/dev/sda1       46377792 44369504         0 100% /
```

This showed that the disk was full. So I allocated 15GB more disk to the virtual machine (GCP Compute Engine). This was shortly all consumed by the OS and the disk maxed out again.

**What I've tried**

Upon investigation, I discovered all the data was begin stored within the system `.cache/pip/http`. Which showed:

```
root@serval-1:~/.cache/pip/http# du --max-depth=1 -h
42M     ./3
25M     ./c
13M     ./8
22M     ./4
15M     ./a
1.4M    ./e
20M     ./6
2.4M    ./9
6.6M    ./d
57M     ./1
3.2M    ./7
676K    ./5
16M     ./b
2.9M    ./2
1.2M    ./f
660K    ./0
226M    .
```

*(The `http` module is used fairly often in my code base so showing all uses of it within this question wouldnt be so useful, although happy to provide if required).*

As a temporary measure I have removed this `.cache` and restarted the VM. This worked and dropped the overall storage by **50%**. Like so:

```
/dev/sda1      46377792     21769340     22600164  50% /
```

But does not provide an explanation of the behavior or prevent occurrence.

Any information on what `pip\http` is and why it is behaving like this would be really useful for a permanent measure.

Comment: `where a python script` show the python script... Please create an [MCVE] `by excessive cache from pip` how do you know it's "excessive"?

Comment: _226MiB_ does not seem excessive to me. For info it has nothing to do with a _http_ module. -- If I am not mistaken this is where _pip_ keeps a copy of downloaded artifacts, in order to speed up following remote requests, this can probably be disabled with [--no-cache-dir](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#cmdoption-no-cache-dir).

Comment: I'm curious to why it says `226M` which when deleted removes 50% of the total storage? which leaves the free storage as `22600164` bytes. *Note `.cache` amounted to `226M`*

Comment: I'm confused. What is the question? I don't see what is unexpected in this behavior.